# Difference between LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT and SetHorizontalExtent

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there any difference between these two possibilities for adding horizontal scroll to CListBox in MFC?

```
::SendMessage( myListBox, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, width, 0 );
```

and

```
myListBox.SetHorizontalExtent(width);
```

Comment: They do the same thing. But ::SendMessage uses an HWND, while myListBox is a CListBox (that has an HWND member). You can single-step into myListBox.SetHorizontalExtent to see for yourself what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a difference internally. However I would definitely prefer:

```
myListBox.SetHorizontalExtent(width);
```

because it is clearer.